# I ran into an error when using Pragma Solidity 0.4.24

Tags: solidity, truffle, solc, truffle-compile

I use pragma solidity 0.4.24 on the smart contract, but when running the truffle compile command, an error appears like this:

```
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/ImageRegister.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol

/Users/adobe/Downloads/an_drive/contracts/ImageRegister.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity 0.4.24;
^---------------------^
,/Users/adobe/Downloads/an_drive/contracts/Migrations.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity 0.4.24;
^---------------------^

Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.16, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity 0.4.24".
Please update your truffle config or pragma statement(s).
(See https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#compiler-configuration for information on
configuring Truffle to use a specific solc compiler version.)

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.3.3 (core: 5.3.3)
Node v12.17.0
```

I'm very confused about how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration says, set the compile version in truffle.js

```
 module.exports = {
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: <string>, // A version or constraint - Ex. "^0.5.0"
                         // Can also be set to "native" to use a native solc
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @smart contract_research_Rookie